# PHP string accented character changing

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, elfinder

I'm using elFinder as file explore with a PHP conector ([elFinder Documentation](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options)), I've configured the Sanitizer plugin ([Sanitizer plugin](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/blob/master/php/plugins/Sanitizer/plugin.php)) with a calback function.

```
function sanitize($filename){ // Or @callable sanitize function
    $a = pathinfo($filename);
    $b = strtourl($a['filename'],false).'.'.$a['extension'];
    echo $b;

    return $b;
}

function strtourl($str, $toLower = true){
    $sr = array('À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'Ā', 'ā', 'Ă', 'ă', 'Ą', 'ą', 'Ć', 'ć', 'Ĉ', 'ĉ', 'Ċ', 'ċ', 'Č', 'č', 'Ď', 'ď', 'Đ', 'đ', 'Ē', 'ē', 'Ĕ', 'ĕ', 'Ė', 'ė', 'Ę', 'ę', 'Ě', 'ě', 'Ĝ', 'ĝ', 'Ğ', 'ğ', 'Ġ', 'ġ', 'Ģ', 'ģ', 'Ĥ', 'ĥ', 'Ħ', 'ħ', 'Ĩ', 'ĩ', 'Ī', 'ī', 'Ĭ', 'ĭ', 'Į', 'į', 'İ', 'ı', 'Ĳ', 'ĳ', 'Ĵ', 'ĵ', 'Ķ', 'ķ', 'Ĺ', 'ĺ', 'Ļ', 'ļ', 'Ľ', 'ľ', 'Ŀ', 'ŀ', 'Ł', 'ł', 'Ń', 'ń', 'Ņ', 'ņ', 'Ň', 'ň', 'ŉ', 'Ō', 'ō', 'Ŏ', 'ŏ', 'Ő', 'ő', 'Œ', 'œ', 'Ŕ', 'ŕ', 'Ŗ', 'ŗ', 'Ř', 'ř', 'Ś', 'ś', 'Ŝ', 'ŝ', 'Ş', 'ş', 'Š', 'š', 'Ţ', 'ţ', 'Ť', 'ť', 'Ŧ', 'ŧ', 'Ũ', 'ũ', 'Ū', 'ū', 'Ŭ', 'ŭ', 'Ů', 'ů', 'Ű', 'ű', 'Ų', 'ų', 'Ŵ', 'ŵ', 'Ŷ', 'ŷ', 'Ÿ', 'Ź', 'ź', 'Ż', 'ż', 'Ž', 'ž', 'ſ', 'ƒ', 'Ơ', 'ơ', 'Ư', 'ư', 'Ǎ', 'ǎ', 'Ǐ', 'ǐ', 'Ǒ', 'ǒ', 'Ǔ', 'ǔ', 'Ǖ', 'ǖ', 'Ǘ', 'ǘ', 'Ǚ', 'ǚ', 'Ǜ', 'ǜ', 'Ǻ', 'ǻ', 'Ǽ', 'ǽ', 'Ǿ', 'ǿ');
    $rp = array('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AE', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'D', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y', 's', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'IJ', 'ij', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'OE', 'oe', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Y', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 's', 'f', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'AE', 'ae', 'O', 'o');

    $url = $str;
    if($toLower) $url = strtolower($url);

    $url = preg_replace('/\s+/', "-", $url);
    $url = str_replace($sr, $rp, $url);
    $url = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+/i', "-", $url);
    $url = preg_replace('/-{2,}/', "-", $url);
    $url = preg_replace('/-+$/', "", $url);

    return $url;
}
```

If I call this function manualy with a custom string works perfectly. If I replace the $filename with a custom string when is called by the plugin it works perfectly.

But the file name that arrives from the plugin is modified when any function touches the string. Let me explain.

Plugin -> sanitize("Camión Avión.jpg")

If I comment everything and echo the $filename, the output is the expected `Camión Avión.jpg` but if I uncomment everything and echo the $filename at the start of the function, the output is `CamioÌn AvioÌn.jpg`, but before $filename was echoed nothing was made.

Let's go more ahead, if I remove my custom function strtourl() and I try the next:

```
function Sanitize($filename){
    var_dump($filename);
    var_dump($filename{5});
    var_dump($filename{6});
    var_dump($filename{7});
}
```

The result is:

```
string(20) "CamioÌn AvioÌn.jpg" 
string(1) "Ì"
string(1) ""
string(1) "n"
```

Where in ascii UTF-8, "Ì" is 204 and "" 129 codes.

If I comment the las 3 lines:

```
function Sanitize($filename){
    var_dump($filename);
    //var_dump($filename{5});
    //var_dump($filename{6});
    //var_dump($filename{7});
}
```

The result is: `string(20) "Camión Avión.jpg"`

I don't know what can be happening, could someone help me?.

Thank you.

Comment: `204`,`129` is UTF-8 byte sequence for the `U+0301` _Combining Acute Accent_.  Use Unicode normalization: your string isn't normalized. A PoSh example: `'Camión Avión'.Normalize('FormKD')` gives something like ```Camio`n Avio`n```…

Comment: Another PoSh example: `'Camión Avión'.Normalize("FormKD") -replace '\p{M}', ''` returns `Camion Avion`.

Comment: `'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĲĳĴĵĶķĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŉŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸŹźŻżŽžſƒƠơƯưǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔǕǖǗǘǙǚǛǜǺǻǼǽǾǿ'.Normalize("FormKD") -replace '\p{M}|·|ʼ'` returns `AAAAAAÆCEEEEIIIIÐNOOOOOØUUUUYßaaaaaaæceeeeiiiinoooooøuuuuyyAaAaAaCcCcCcCcDdĐđEeEeEeEeEeGgGgGgGgHhĦħIiIiIiIiIıIJijJjKkLlLlLlLlŁłNnNnNnnOoOoOoŒœRrRrRrSsSsSsSsTtTtŦŧUuUuUuUuUuUuWwYyYZzZzZzsƒOoUuAaIiOoUuUuUuUuUuAaÆæØø`; if I add `-replace "[a-zA-Z]"` I get `ÐØßæøĐđĦħıŁłŒœŦŧƒÆæØø` - a minimal string for _manual_ replace `strtourl` func…

Answer (score 0):

Finaly as @JosefZ commented, it was a normalization problem. The elFinder connector provides a plugin to Normilize the filename too before sanitizing it. [Normalizer Plugin](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/blob/master/php/plugins/Normalizer/plugin.php)

This is my final configuration:

```
         $opts = array(
            'bind' => array(
                'upload.pre mkdir.pre mkfile.pre rename.pre archive.pre ls.pre' => array(
                    'Plugin.Normalizer.cmdPreprocess',
                    'Plugin.Sanitizer.cmdPreprocess'
                ),
                'upload.presave paste.copyfrom' => array(
                    'Plugin.Normalizer.onUpLoadPreSave',
                    'Plugin.Sanitizer.onUpLoadPreSave'
                )
            ),
            'roots'  => array(
                array(
                    'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem',
                    'path'   => ROOT_PATH,
                    'URL'    => URI.ROOT,
                    "trashHash" => "t2_Lw",
                    'alias'  => $_ENV['WEBID'],
                    'attributes' => $attrs,
                    'plugin' => array(
                        'Normalizer' => array(
                            'enable'    => true,
                            'nfc'       => true,
                            'nfkc'      => true,
                            'umlauts'   => false,
                            'lowercase' => false,
                            'convmap'   => array()
                        ),
                        'Sanitizer' => array(
                            'enable' => true,
                            'targets'  => array('\\','/',':','','?','"','<','>','|'), // target chars
                            'replace'  => '_', // replace to this
                            'callBack' => '\App\Admin\Controllers\Sanitize'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'id'            => '2',
                    'driver'        => 'Trash',
                    'path'          => ROOT_PATH . '/.papelera',
                )
            ),
            'maxTargets' => string2bool($_POST['multiple']) ? null : 1,
            'debug' => DEBUG,
            'locale' => 'es_ES.UTF-8',
            'tmbBgColor' => '#FFFFFF',
            'tmbCrop' => false
        );
```

With this elFinder connector options and the previous functions (strtourl and sanitize callback) it works as expected.

> Note that Normalizer plugin uses PHP Normalizer class that requires intl extension. I've had some troubles installing it on Xampp for Mac but I've found this post which solves the problem. [Intl for Xammp on mac](http://blog.dhawalmehta.com/2019/08/20/install-intl-php-extension-for-xampp-and-magento-for-macos-mojave/)